# search and replace whole string with replacement

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a string that I would like to replace with another one if a word within the string is found.

```
 $pattern = array("/jacket/i","/jeans/i"); 
 $replacement = array("jacket","jeans"); 
 $string = 'Red jackets'; 
 $replaced_string = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

I know the above wont work but i need to be able to use an array of patterns and replacements.

I would like the $replacement_string to be just "**jacket**"

Can someone point me out to a solution for this?

Thanks

Comment: Changed my original answer to something closer to your original code.  All you might have to do is just add `.*` around the original pattern strings... that way it clears out the rest of the string and leaves you with a single, replacement word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe if you tweaked your original code just a bit like this:

```
$patterns = array("/.*jacket.*/i", "/.*jeans.*/i");
$replacements = array("jacket", "jeans");
$string = 'Red jackets';
$replaced_string = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string);
```

Putting those `.*` in there will clear out the rest of the string... and leave you with just the replacement string you want.

Answer (score 2):

You know the above won't work how?

Review the php dev guide: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

I have quoted the noteworthy section:

**pattern**

> The pattern to search for. It can be either a string or an array with
>   strings.

**replacement**

> The string or an array with strings to replace. If this parameter is a
>   string and the pattern parameter is an array, all patterns will be
>   replaced by that string. If both pattern and replacement parameters
>   are arrays, each pattern will be replaced by the replacement
>   counterpart. If there are fewer elements in the replacement array than
>   in the pattern array, any extra patterns will be replaced by an empty
>   string.

So what all that says basically is you can make you're pattern array be all the words you want to replace. Then you can just use the word "jacket" as your replacement and then anytime a word in your pattern array is found it will replace it with jacket.

Are you having problems getting this to work?

Comment: Thank you for informing me about this, regex has been hard to grasp but it is getting clearer that its very powerful and learning it is essential. I had to give this one to @summea because his/her answer was the actual code that I needed. thanks

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
$pattern = array("/jacket/i","/jeans/i"); 
$replacement = array("jacket","jeans"); 
$string = 'Red jackets'; 

foreach ($pattern as $i => $p) {
    if (preg_match($p, $string)) {
        $replaced_string = $replacement[$i];
        break;
    }
}

echo $replaced_string;
```

Comment: @summea: don't you see `break`? This is exactly what OP described in his question, doesn't he?

Comment: @summea: "I would like the $replacement_string to be just "jacket"" --- my code just does that ;-) If that is not what OP meant - he need to start expressing his thoughts better ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the comments...!  You're right about needing to just get one word.  However, using a foreach loop potentially slows down the code depending on how big the pattern and replacement arrays get.  I'm not sure the foreach is necessary when PHP's preg_replace can work with pattern and replacement arrays... but, there is often more than one way to do things... with PHP.

Comment: @summea: well - do the same without `foreach`. I'd like to see how it would be possible ;-) `potentially slows` means nothing. Do you experience any particular issues with *this solution*? Do you have another? Thoughts? ;-)

Comment: see my answer above for a foreach-less way :)

Comment: @summea: you modified the regexes - it changes the initial requirements, that doesn't count

Comment: @summea: also - just FYI - when `preg_replace` accepts array - it also performs **iteration** over regexes, which is the same thing foreach does. And don't forget that to replace string using regex pattern is **slower** than just create string from the scratch. Keep that in mind when you next time say "it is potentially slows"

Comment: does the OP say not to modify the patterns?

Comment: @summea: do you have anything to say about "potentially slows"?