# How to fill a pattern with some values in an array

Tags: php, regex

I have a uri pattern and i want to fill it with some values.
i have Just this two variables.

```
$pattern = "/^(?P<scope>[a-zA-Z]+)\/(?P<node>[a-zA-Z]+)\/(?P<controller>[a-zA-Z]+)\/(?P<action>[a-zA-Z]+)$/";

$replacement = array('scope'=>'Modules', 'node'=>'Index', 'controller'=>'Index', 'action'=>'index');
```

and i'm looking for a way to have this output : Modules/Index/Index/index

Thank You !

Comment: It's not necessarily possible to reverse a regular expression; Zend Framework get around this in their routers by using a sprintf format to specify how to re-assemble the route: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.regex (see the last 2 examples in that section)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$output = substr($pattern, 2, -2);
$output = stripcslashes($output);
foreach ($replacement as $key => $value)
    $output = str_replace("(?P<$key>[a-zA-Z]+)", $value, $output);
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful, depending on your URI, though it uses PHP's str_replace as opposed to a regex ...

```
$oldURI  = 'blah/<scope>/<node>/<controller>/<action>/';
$search  = array('<scope>','<node>','<controller>','<action>');
$replace = array('Modules','Index','Index','index');
$newURI  = str_replace($search, $replace, $oldURI);
```

Comment: Thank You ! but unfortunately i used regex all over my project ! i wrote a routing system using regex :D now i have a linkAnchor class that passes a controller's namespace and returns a decorated link. and it have to search in the regex list and find the match one :(

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9041346/search-and-replace-whole-string-with-replacement answer the question?

Comment: since i used string for pattern i won't be able to use an array for replacement. thank you